# Error al eliminar registros de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Mi codigo no muestra errores pero al querer utilizar el boton me lanza este error, quisiera saber como solucionarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo del boton "QUITAR"

```
 private void BtnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach(DataGridViewRow item in DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows)
      {
          DataGridViewSelectionArea.RemoveAt(item.Index);

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vinculaste el `DataGridView` a un `origen de datos`, no puedes eliminar items directamente en el control, tienes que eliminar la row del DataTable y volver a bindear para que se actualice

Por otro lados si defines una columna Id esta deberia ser unica para cada item, alli veo que tienes un 1 como Prueba y el mismo 1 para Bar, si es Id no se puede duplicar, sino deja de ser Id
Si quieres usar las `SelectedRows` en lugar de los check podrias buscar por id, pero este debe se unico, entonces harias:

```
private void BtnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows == null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un fila del grid");
       return;
    }

    var dt = (DataTable)DataGridViewSelectionArea.DataSource;

    foreach(DataGridViewRow item in DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows)
    {
        var row = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r=> r["Id"] == item.Cells["Id"].Value);

        if(row != null)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }

    DataGridViewSelectionArea.DataSource = dt;

}
```

la idea es buscar en los datos que vinculaste al Grid para eliminar estos y al final volver a mostrarlos

Comment: se mira muy bien tu codigo incluso navege por tu blog todo muy bueno, pero me lanza un error al qoerer ejecutar el boton de Quitar

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: El mismo de la imagen

Comment: Si es mejor el check me podrias decir como usarlo, lo que quiero es que las filas que tengan activada el checkbox se eliminen

Comment: pero estas seleccionado alguna row en el grid ? porque sino lo haces quizas debas validarlo. Edite el codigo del ejemplo para que veas la validacion

Comment: Ya vi si me lo muestra como null pero si esta seleccionado, te adjunto un screen: https://ibb.co/NmkK7hL

Comment: Es que hay otro factor muy raro, tu que tienes muchisima mas experiencia... los datos con el boton de agregar me los pasa ya con el check activado, y en el grid de lado derecho no se pueden despalomear el check

Comment: la propiedad SelectedRows no son los checkbox, debe resaltarse la row seleccionandola. Para los check debes validar el Value de la celda

Comment: si te pasa los valores activos es porque seguramente asignas el valor que venia del otro grid, cuando el Value de esa celda deberias asignarla en false

Comment: Este es mi boton de "agregar" http://dpaste.com/05NPFWC

Comment: para que no marque el check quizas debas usar rowDestino["Sel"] = false; asi pasara siempre desmarcado

Comment: Mm si los deja seleccionados algunos pero se llaman  false https://ibb.co/TYmh0ND

Comment: Actualizo : https://ibb.co/Ht6ZpjN 

El otro factor es que en el grid de lado de la derecha no me deja seleccionarlos

Comment: Ya logre hacer que todos los checkbox pasaran unselected, pero ahora no me deja seleccionar alguno simplemente, presiono el checkbox y no hace nada, sabras por que??

Comment: Otra cosa que no logro entender porque pasa, es que aun que no seleccione nada en los datagrid de la izquiera de igual forma me trae estos: https://ibb.co/xDVfTTf

Comment: pero no estas marcando ningun checkbox, tienes que editar la celda del check para poder cambiarla, valida qe el grid no este con la propiedad readonly en true

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no tengo el datagridview como en si en la interfaz, lo tengo escrito en codigo y al ejecutar ya se muestran, este es el codigo del datagridview como agregaria la propiedad readonly en true: 
http://dpaste.com/2KF2QGJ

aqui te muestro como se ve la interfaz grafica sin ejecutar : https://ibb.co/CB3zHjm

De antemano, gracias

Comment: Agregue la linea :this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.ReadOnly = true; al codigo del datagridview
Pero me sigue mandando el messagebox de "debes seleccionar la fila del grid"
Dando a entender que no marca ningun row como seleccionado

Comment: Ni tampoco me deja "palomear" los checkbox simplemente no hace nada

Comment: No se eliminan como lo dije aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226877/boton-quitar-c-form-button/226933?noredirect=1#comment421769_226933