# Boton < Quitar c# form button

Tags: c#

Hola quiero hacer que las filas seleccionadas se eliminen
asi se mira la interfaz 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que llevo pero no queda

```
 private void BtnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar una fila del grid");
            return;
        }
        var dt = (DataTable)DataGridViewSelectionArea.DataSource;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows)
        {
            var row = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["Id"] == item.Cells["Id"].Value);
            if (row != null)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
            DataGridViewSelectionArea.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Pero no cumple su funcion, al momento de usar el boton me manda el messagebox de "debe seleccionar una fila" y cuando intento seleccionar el checkbox no me deja palomearlo, se queda como esta imposible de palomearlo, yo solo quiero quitar la fila de los checkbox seleccionados al darle al boton de quitar

Este el el codigo del DataGridViewSelectionArea:

```
  this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 250);
    this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Name = "DataGridViewSelectionArea";
    this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 230);

    this.Controls.Add(this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView);
```

*Cada que quiero quitar una fila me lanza el MessageBox de "Debes selecionar una fila del grid" y quiero que se eliminen las filas del checkbox seleccionados, de a ante manos, gracias.*

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta tiene que ser mas clara? que quiere decir que no queda? que es lo que hace? que deberia hacer? que no hace?

Comment: Listo ya lo leí y he editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás realizando la asignación del DataTable dt dentro del mismo bucle foreach donde lo modificas, es normal que esto provoque comportamientos extraños.

Saca esta línea del foreach y mira a ver si así te funciona:

```
DataGridViewSelectionArea.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Hola, ya la quite y el problema persiste, mi primer problema es que no puedo seleccionar(palomear) los checkbox del datagrid de la derecha para asi seleccionar que fila borrar

Comment: Encontre esta solucion:
Hola, despues de leer un poco más lo soluciones  utilizando el evento onmouseclick de la celda

y alli para la columna del checkbox que queria que fuera editable, utilice beginedit = true  y así lo solucione dejando las demás columnas desahabilitadas.

Pero no me explico como aplicarla

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares a tu pregunta le falta mucha informacion. Como esta definida esa grilla? como es el datasource que le pasas? el campo que estas pasando al combo es booleano?

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta es correcta, no termina de contestar la pregunta, porque el problema es mayor que solo esto. Por favor mira [answer]. Gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: No he encontado la solucion

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares no se si entiendo entonces cual es tu problema. Se supone que quieres primero seleccionar una serie de filas del grid "DataGridViewSelectionArea" y despues hacer click en "Quitar" y que se eliminen, ¿no? ¿Puedes indicar cual es el problema que te da?

Comment: exacto @M.Nacher El problema es que al darle check al checkbox no se palomea y al darle al boton de quitar me manda el messagebox"Debes seleccionar una fila del grid" Por ende supongo que no se selecciona, no se por que

Comment: Vale, eso parece mas problema de configuración del grid que del botón, edita tu pregunta y muestra cómo está configurado para ver porque no se selecciona nada.

Comment: @M.Nacher Ya lo edite, en el Design no se mira en el form hasta que se ejecuta ya se observe el grid