# Agregar Los datos del checkbox seleccionados a otro grid

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Mi boton de agregar si hace su funcion el problema es que siempre estan los mismos datos en DataGridViewSection area con el dataGridView1 y no quiero eso, quiero que las filas seleccionadas a partir del checkbox de DataGridViewSection  pasen a dataGridView1

```
 private void Agregar()
    {

        var rowsChecked = this.DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));


        foreach (DataRow rowOrigen in rowsChecked)
        {
            DataRow rowDestino = this.DataTableSection.NewRow();
            rowDestino["Sel"] = false;
            rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"];
            rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
            this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
        }
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableSection;
    }
```

Ilustración Grafica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano gracias y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: a que llamas grid de origen ? en el codigo de Quitar() veo que solo actua sobre el dataGridView1, pero no veo donde vuelves asignar el DataSource despues de quitar las rows seleccionadas

Comment: ademas si iteras por dataGridView1.SelectedRows, deberias en el FirstOrDefault comparar Id, no la columna Sel

Comment: El grid origen es de donde traigo los datos hacia el DataGridView1 y lo hace pero al eliminar del DataGridView1 tambien elimino en este caso los de DataGridSectionArea (Simultaneamente) como si los datos estuvieran conectados y se reflejaran iguales

Comment: Si Comparo con Id no me elimina la fila, solo selecciona el checkbox

Comment: si usas r => r["Id"] == item.Cells["Id"].Value no elimina ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Es correcto, no me elimina

Comment: viendo el codigo Quitar() no entiendo siquiera porque te esta removiendo nada del DataGridView1 porque a final falta la linea `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: La misma situación, no cambio, algo que quieras que te muestre? si de algo ayuda al darle agregar sin seleccionar nada siempre me trae las filas de DataGridViewSectionArea ( el grid de la izquiera abajo )

Comment: He estado leyendo el codigo y yo pienso que el problema es del AGREGAR()
Por si si miramos le dice que la variable rowDestino sea lo mismoa que DataTableSection,.... Pero en ese caso como podria reprogramar el boton de AGREGAR() para que me traiga los datos que esten true del checkbox¿?

Comment: Esta es la tercer pregunta referido al mismo tema y para lo cual preguntas lo mismo. o me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Te equivocas, supongo puedes ver las ediciones, ahorita el problema es que los datos en dos grids siempre son los mismos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Boton < Quitar c# form button](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226877/boton-quitar-c-form-button)